# Separating "flags" from "arguments" in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I'm working with a legacy shell script that's used for testing certain features in binaries (i.e. calls `nm`, `objdump`, `ldd`, etc; and does some parsing on the results). The shell script currently is very "touchy", and large, so I'd like to minimize changes I make to it.

It currently starts with a check for the number of parameters, each one being a path, i.e.:

```
if [ "$#" -lt 3 ]
then
  echo "Error. Invalid number of arguments."
  exit
fi
```

I would like to add some additional arguments and their long-form equivalents to disable certain features internal to the script, without invalidating the above test, i.e.:

```
-h | --help: Print shell usage and expected arguments.
-x | --xfer: Do some extra copy logic.
-d | --dry:  Do a dry-run, and don't actually change any files.
```

However, I do not want the flags (i.e. arguments that begin with a hyphen) to be counted as arguments (i.e. doesn't affect the assignment of parameters to `$1`, `$2`, and `$3`). For example, the following is currently a valid invocation of my script:

```
bash ./test.sh ./ ./out ./logs
```

I would like the following possible invocations to also work:

```
bash ./test.sh ./ ./out ./logs --dry
bash ./test.sh --xfer ./ ./out ./logs
bash ./test.sh --help
bash ./test.sh ./ --xfer ./out --dry ./logs
```

How would I setup a script to "filter out" arguments that begin with hyphens (one or two), and maintain the same assignments to `$1`, `$2`,and `$3`?

Comment: BTW, if noninvasiveness were your *first* goal, I'd be accepting these options through the environment rather than on the command line at all.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Good point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify the argument list after-the-fact:

```
set -- one two three
```

Thus, you can put your own parsing up at the top, and use `set --` to put whatever arguments you want in place into their desired positions.

---

Consider as an example of filtering:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^- not /bin/sh, as arrays are bash-only

help_and_exit() {
  local retval=${1:-1}
  cat <<EOF
${0##*/} [-d|--dry-run] [-x|--xfer] input output whatever

...put your extended help here...
EOF
  exit "$retval"
}

args=( )
dry_run=0; xfer=0
while (( $# )); do
  case $1 in
    -d|--dry)  dry_run=1 ;;
    -x|--xfer) xfer=1 ;;
    -h|--help) help_and_exit 0 ;;
    -*)        printf 'Unknown option: %q\n\n' "$1"
               help_and_exit 1 ;;
    *)         args+=( "$1" ) ;;
  esac
  shift
done
set -- "${args[@]}"
```

Comment: One more question: how would I modify this so that certain flags could have an argument, and I don't want that `optarg` being interpreted as an argument to the script itself? i.e. `-d` expects a single argument to follow it. Thank you.

Comment: `-d) dry_run=$2; shift ;;` -- see [BashFAQ #35](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035).

Comment: You might also handle `--dry=*` and `-d*` with their own `case` blocks there (setting `dry_run=${1#*=}` or `dry_run=${1#-d}`, respectively, ordering those blocks so the `-d` one gets called in favor to `-d*` if the string is empty).